# Customize ControlsFX Notifications

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, controlsfx

I want to use [ControlsFX Notifications](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/index.html?org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html) class, as JavaFX seems to doesn't offer anything like it (or does it?).

[image: Notification by ControlsFX]

For me to use it I want to be able to customize the color of the notification and some other styles. Does anybody have an idea of how I can do that?

**Edit:**

Through setting `Notifications.owner(...)` the notification is styled the same way as my main application, **but** it is then shown within the main application as well and not at the bottom right corner of my screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Notifications.create().title(...).text(..).action(...).position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT).show();`

Through using this line in Java and adding following lines **at the bottom of my stylesheet** I was able to customize the notification.

```css
.notification-bar>.pane {
    -fx-background-color: red, yellow, blue;
    -fx-padding: 5 5 5 5;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}

.notification-bar>.pane .title {
    -fx-font-size: 1.333em; /*16px;*/
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.notification-bar>.pane .label {
    -fx-font-size: 1em; /*12px;*/
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
    -fx-alignment: top-left;
}

/******************************************************************************
 * 
 * Close button
 * 
 *****************************************************************************/

.notification-bar>.pane .close-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}

.notification-bar > .pane .close-button:hover {
     -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#a3a3a3, #8b8b8b 34%, #777777 36%, #777777 63%, #8b8b8b 65%, #adadad);
}

.notification-bar>.pane .close-button:pressed {
     -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#a3a3a3, #8b8b8b 34%, #777777 36%, #777777 63%, #8b8b8b 65%, #adadad):

}

.notification-bar>.pane .close-button>.graphic {
     -fx-background-color: #fff;
     -fx-scale-shape: false;
     -fx-padding: 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5; /* Graphic is 9x9 px */
}

.notification-bar>.pane .close-button:hover>.graphic {
     -fx-background-color: #fff;
}

.notification-bar>.pane .close-button:pressed>.graphic {
     -fx-background-color: #fff;
}

.notification-bar>.pane .close-button>.graphic {
     -fx-shape:
    "M395.992,296.758l1.794-1.794l7.292,7.292l-1.795,1.794 L395.992,296.758z M403.256,294.992l1.794,1.794l-7.292,7.292l-1.794-1.795 L403.256,294.992z";
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: `BOTTOM_RIGHT` is the default, you don't have to specidy it manually. :)

Comment: how do you set the stylesheet for the notification that you create?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14697419/5493813