# How can I do an error messages in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I want to make error message like this on JavaFX. How can I do it?

[image: half transparent error message above ui]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2 custom popup pane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717969/javafx-2-custom-popup-pane)

Answer (score 7):

Use an [`Alert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html):

```
Alert errorAlert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
errorAlert.setHeaderText("Input not valid");
errorAlert.setContentText("The size of First Name must be between 2 and 25 characters");
errorAlert.showAndWait();
```

Answer (score 4):

> ~~>Default Way

Alert class and some more are already in JavaFX library a full tutorial  [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)

How to costumize an Alert?[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354686/costumize-javafx-alert-with-css)

> ^^Using ControlsFX library^^

There is a ready JavaFX library that make messages like in your icon.I am talking about [ControlsFX library](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/)

> ~~>More Costumizable

It contains a Class named [NotificationPane](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/NotificationPane.html) which you can modify in the way you want to display messages like JavaFX `Alert` and more complicated.

> ~~>For your situation

I would use [Notifications](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html) class which display messages in the bootom,top,right,left and combination of them in the screen.

Example Code:

```
Notifications.create() .title("Title Text") .text("Hello World 0!") .showWarning();
```

Image:

[Look here](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/notifications.png) Edit this cause for some reason isn't displayed in stackoverflow

> ~~>How to costumize Notifications:

[Customize ControlsFX Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494089/customize-controlsfx-notifications)

Comment: Glad to hear.When an answer is providing what you asked you can accept it.