# Customize ControlsFX Notification Popup using CSS

Tags: css, javafx, controlsfx, javafx-css

I am using the ControlsFX `Notifications` class to create a notification popup. Everything about it is great, except for the fact that I can't style it with CSS. From the research that I did, it says you must add a `Notifications.owner()`, and the notification popup will then adopt the same stylesheet as whatever owner you put in. So far I've tried `Notification.owner(root)`, `Notification.owner(stage)`, and `Notification.owner(scene)`. All of them had been set with my stylesheet, but none of them worked. Any ideas?

Here is my CSS:

```
/*Notification styling------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.notification-bar > .pane {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-padding: 5 5 5 5;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
}

.notification-bar > .pane .title {
    -fx-font-size: 1.333em; /*16px;*/
    -fx-text-fill: purple;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.notification-bar > .pane .label {
    -fx-font-size: 1em; /*12px;*/
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-alignment: top-left;
}

/******************************************************************************
 *
 * Close button
 *
 *****************************************************************************/

.notification-bar > .pane .close-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}

.notification-bar > .pane .close-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: brown;
}

.notification-bar > .pane .close-button:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: orange;
}

.notification-bar > .pane .close-button > .graphic {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
    -fx-scale-shape: false;
    -fx-padding: 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5; /* Graphic is 9x9 px */
}

.notification-bar > .pane .close-button:hover > .graphic {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.notification-bar > .pane .close-button:pressed > .graphic {
    -fx-background-color: gold;
}

.notification-bar > .pane .close-button > .graphic {
    -fx-shape: "M395.992,296.758l1.794-1.794l7.292,7.292l-1.795,1.794 L395.992,296.758z M403.256,294.992l1.794,1.794l-7.292,7.292l-1.794-1.795 L403.256,294.992z";
}
```

Here is how I'm creating my notification:

```
Notifications
                .create()
                .owner(PageManager.root)
                .title("Submission Complete")
                .text("You successfully added a new user")
                .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(3))
                .position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT)
                .graphic(imageView)
                .show();
```

`PageManager.root` is the root that my entire application uses. I set the stylesheet on it and it works on everything else in my application except the notification.

*Side note: I don't think the issue is with the CSS. I'm using copied CSS from a verified stackoverflow answer that apparently fixed my exact issue. For some reason, I can't get that solution to work. Here is the OG post [Customize ControlsFX Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494089/customize-controlsfx-notifications)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.